# Tag synonyms: Composition and Songwriting.

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Tag synonyms: [composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition) and [songwriting](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/songwriting).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songwriter) said that:

> A songwriter is an individual who writes songs and can also be called a composer.

So I assume that songwriting is similar to composition.

Comment: Surely songwriting is a more specific version of composition? I always understood that synonyms were for tags which represented the same concept, not were a subset of each other.

Comment: I'd agree with Chris - these aren't the same, one is a subset of the other, so best not to have them as synonyms

Answer (score 12):

There is certainly some overlap, but I see these as different concepts. Many composers would not consider themselves songwriters, and many songwriters would not consider themselves composers.

Answer (score 7):

These terms are not synonyms. A song implies the act of singing, therefore the person who **composes songs** is a **songwriter**. **Composer** is more generic, as a composer can create music featuring a whole universe of instrumental/technical/aesthetical possibilities, of which songs are just a subset.

I see a lot of confusion here at Music.SE regarding the use of the word *song*, as it is often used regardless of whether the musical work features singing or not.

I am myself a composer, but I very seldom compose songs. I do compose most of the time, but only a small subset of this activity can be considered *songwriting*.

Comment: +1 for making me use Wikipedia looking for something I actually did not know

Comment: agreed -- I would not make a tag synonym. Or if there were one, only keep it until the site is sufficiently established w/ questions to de-link them later.